# Book about intelligent, mating comets and physically connected planets

Tags: story-identification

A decade or two ago, I read a sci-fi series (at least two books) about super strong stretchy material connecting the planets, with an ominous conqueror taking over. And then there were the intelligent comets which could move themselves around by converting a bit of mass into energy.

Additional details I remember: humans have digital/nanobot immune systems; when there are military attacks these get taken out.

There’s also a sentient being that sometimes occupies a car and can teleport.

I think I read until the asteroids and outer planet humans teamed up to combat the conqueror in the physically webbed together inner system.

I can’t for the life of me remember the name of the novels.

Comment: "novels": so it's a series of books then? Not just a single book? Apart from that, you might want to take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) to see if it triggers any more memories that you could edit in :)

Comment: Yup, at least two books

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like [Metaplanetary](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?20966) and [Superluminal](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?30994) by Tony Daniel

The inner solar system is connected by the Met, a system of living cables. The tyrant Amés has declared that artificial intelligences are non-human and only fit to be enslaved. The entire system is filled with "grist", a sort of ubiquitous nanotechnology that among other things functions as a system wide internet. There are huge nebular comet-like things called "cloudships" which move by controlled matter-antimatter reactions, they are warships. Combat not only occurs on physical levels with soldiers and guns, but also on nanotechnological levels. Genius physicist Li is sent to Earth where she meets an 800 year old sentient Jeep.